# Where should a javascript developer start to create a desktop browser?

Tags: javascript, desktop-application

I have a project where I need to create a desktop app that acts like a browser, however, I need to be able to execute my own css and javascript on ANY page that a user goes to. The goal is to have a user be able to browse to a website, and then click on certain elements of the site and quickly pull information regarding that element (divID, classes, etc), then add some javascript inside the browser that will add some new functionality to the page (though only in the browser).  I'll also need to sync this desktop app up to both an internal database as well as connect to a remote database online.

I'm a javascript developer, and so I really want to be able to use jquery to help build out the interaction with the site.  I've played around with adobe air, and was able to build a browser using flex, but then I wasn't able to use jquery to manipulate the pages (maybe there's a way, but I don't know flex at all, and I couldn't figure it out and didn't want to waste too much time to discover that I couldn't do it).  I then tried to create an HTML air app and have the browser essentially be an iframe.  However, the cross domain scripting became an issue, and I don't think that the iframe sandBox solution is what I'm after because that looks like I would need to create a local version for each page that is browsed to, and then alter that local version.

So, I'm back to square one and am trying to find what technology I should be looking at where I can add my own javascript and css to a page within a browser?  I'm familiar with javascript and PHP, but this will be my first desktop app.  I'm willing to learn a new technology though I obviously want to be able to stick to what I'm most familiar with.  I've thought about building a firefox plugin, but I'm hoping to sell this app, and I think a stand alone app would allow for a higher price tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/).  It's cross platform, has the ability to create "real" apps, can load and process HTML and CSS (has webkit built in), and allows for the [creation of applications using HTML/CSS/JavaScript](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2010/7/31/Building-your-first-HTMLAdobe-AIR-Application).  If you're looking for something more freedom loving, check out [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/), which is a similar framework.

Comment: Is there a way to inject your javascript into the page that the flex webkit provides?  There might be, but I wasn't able to find the answer.